# Can cups snmp v1 cause security issues?

Tags: snmp

I found out that one of the devices in the network is using cups to identify printers.

After more digging, I found out that cups is using snmp v1 which is a deprecated version and can cause some security issues.

Can cups snmp v1 cause security issues?

Comment: You swapped questions. Can snmpv1 cause security issues? Yes, that's well-documented. Can ***these unnamed devices*** be upgraded to use snmp v3? You need to read the documentation or ask the vendor.

Comment: Have you googled "cups snmp"?

Comment: yes I did , but I am finding nothing about snmpv3 for cups . And the one page of documentation gives nothing useful

Comment: The relevant detail is whether you have snmp running on services in your network. Do you?